# Running curl command on remote server from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to execute the curl command from Jenkins declarative pipeline on a remote server, however it is running on Jenkins node instead of server.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 
    }
    stages {
        stage('TEst ssh') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh '''
                    ssh -t user@test << ENDSSH
                    echo "ssh to server"
                    cd /opt/apps
                    url=$(curl -H 'X-JFrog-Art-Api: Artifactory_token' 'Artifactory_url' |jq -r '.uri')
                    echo $url
ENDSSH
'''
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

I am getting "Curl command not found". can anyone suggest a solution for the same?

Answer (score 0):

Just put the full path to curl in the command, `/bin/curl`? Or change the cmd to `set` and check tbe path, then figure out why `/bin` is not in the path or if curl is even there.

Note: remote ssh login is not the same login sequence as a remote shell.